# WPF Datagrid showing columns twice

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid

I have successfully displayed data in datagrid by binding it to database columns, but problem is that , all the data columns comes twice after displaying completely i.e (id, user_id,status,id, user_id,status,).how to get out of this, here is my code

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Grid_display" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="63,51,36,10" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path=id}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Publisher ID" Binding="{Binding Path=user_id}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Publication Title" Binding="{Binding Path=title}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Published Date of Document" Binding="{Binding Path=published_date}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="File" Binding="{Binding Path=file}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Path=status}"/>

                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>

 private void display_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<publication> q = (from p in db.publications where p.user_id == get_id select p).ToList();
            Grid_display.ItemsSource = q;

        }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You will have to set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` on your datagrid. By default it is true and is adding another set of columns.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Grid_display" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          Margin="63,51,36,10" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
```

Comment: ya this should be the answer :)